# Probability. Exclusive and Non Exclusive Events

Tags: probability

An integer is chosen at random from the first 50 integers. A is the event 'divisible by 2', B is the event divisible by 3, C is the event divisible by 5.
Find P(A and B)

Can someone please hint me on how you do this question, ive attempted and failed.Thankyou

Comment: Make a list of all the elements in $A$, in $B$, and _count_ the number of elements in $A\cup B$. After you have done that, figure out how many elements there are in $A \cap B$ and try to figure out why you might have been able to figure out $|A|$, $|B|$ and $|A\cap B|$ without _listing and counting_ the elements and why it is true that $$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|.$$

Comment: Sorry, but could you please tell me what values are A, B and C. I've been placing my own values into the equation and it still comes out the wrong answer

Comment: Integers divisible by $2$ can be written in the form $2k$ where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: So is A 1/2 or 25?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Dilip Sarwate actually took the solution one step further and introduced some set theory into it. I shall break it down simply and illustrate what he meant. Let's just use the first $20$ integers. In other words, $\{1, 2, \cdots, 20\}$. He let the set $\bf{A}$ be the set of numbers divisible by $2$ and $\bf{B}$ be the set of numbers divisible by $3$. I shall assume $A$ and $B$ would mean the number is "divisible by $2$ and divisible by $3$". Hence, you are finding $\text{Pr}(A\cap B)$.

In my example, $\bf A$ = $\{2, 4, \cdots, 20\}$ and hence $\text{Pr}(A)=\frac{10}{20}$.

Also, $\bf B$ = $\{3, 6, \cdots, 18\}$ and hence $\text{Pr}(B)=\frac{6}{20}$.

To find $\bf A \cap \bf B$, simply count the elements that exist **both** in sets $\bf A$ and $\bf B$. How many elements are there? Divide that number by $20$ and you should get your answer. With regards to his final statement
\begin{equation}\bf A \cup \bf B = \bf A + \bf B - (\bf A \cap \bf B)\end{equation}

Basically, form a **set** of elements which exist in both sets $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ (DO NOT DOUBLE-COUNT ELEMENTS...the definition of a set already means it contains unique elements). It is actually the set of elements in $\bf A$ added to $\bf B$, and then you subtract the elements in both sets $\bf A$ and $\bf B$, to take care of the double-counting.